# JavaFX 2.0 how to "pin" a stage to another stage

Tags: java, popup, window, javafx-2, stage

So I have a JavaFX 2.0 application, and the main window is shown on startup.  What I want to do is have the user press a button, and have another window pop up next to the main window.

**So, I want an undecorated stage "pinned" to the left of the main stage.**

I know how to make the window, and how to make it undecorated, the new window works fine, **I just want to make it so that it stays in the same position relative to the main window (or stage, whichever you prefer to call it), when that window is moved.**

Answer (score 1):

Just set a listener to reposition your window when its 'buddy' window is repositioned or resized. There may be a lag, since sometimes those events don't get fired until the final new position/size is set, though.

A `Stage` has a `heightProperty` and `widthProperty`, to which you can bind a listener using:

```
stage.widthProperty().addListener(listener);
```

You can do the same with almost any property that's exposed - the position properties, etc.

Your listener needs to implement the `ChangeListener<Number>` interface.

Comment: I wanted to do that, but I don't know the listener to use to check when a window is moved.

Comment: I've added a bit to explain how to do that.